# Renamed an R Source file from my R project. Now the other files can't find it

Tags: r

I was working on R studio, I had a project with 2 .R files.

One is app.R, the other one used to be called test.R, and app.R was able to invoke it's functions without adding anything else, however, I renamed test.R to calculations.R
Now app.R cannot find any of its functions. I already checked the working directory and they're both in the same locations

What can I do to make app.R detect calculations.R?

Comment: Since you were calling functions from `test.R` in `app.R`, was there a line in `app.R` with something like `source("test.R")`?

Comment: Nope, never added any line to reference test.R in app.R

Comment: So how were you using the functions from `test.R` in the first place when only executing lines from `app.R`? You may want to do some [edit]ing of your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sounds like you were expected to build a package and load it but failed to complete that series of tasks.

Comment: @duckmayr I literally didn't do anything to have it read from the file. At first I tried to indicate a `library(test)` but it indicated an error since test isn't actually a package.
I removed the library statement and didn't do anything else, just ran the app, and it ran. So I thought it was able to read from every file in the same working directory of the project.

In any case, I managed to solve it by restarting RStudio and adding a new function to the newly renamed test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds to me like you defined your functions in `test.R`, also ran it there and than started your app. Once you define a function and ran it, no matter what script they are in, this function is within your global environment. That means that you can start your app, without sourcing your `test.R` script. However, you should follow the advice of @duckmayr, because in programming you rather want to make everything explicit.
In order to only have functions which are defined within your app environment, consider using the following command in the beginning of your script:

```r
rm(list = ls())
```

This command will clear your enviroment, so that no unneeded functions, packages, objects and the like are within it.

Comment: It seems that was the issue.
I'll add to the answer, to "import" or "target" other files that your program may need, use source(filePath) at the top of the main file.